# Linear Gradient Effect without Transparency as second color in InkScape?

Tags: inkscape, gradient

I have a problem with my Object that I want to apply a linear gradient onto to simulate a 3D effect (glow on top of a button).

It looks fine in the editor but when exported the gradient area is going to transparency instead to a lighter version of the base color.

When trying to edit it I can't see any way to define the "destination color".
[image]

I'd like to make the destination color (marked with red arrow in screenshot) a lighter red instead of transparent. I can't figure out how to edit that.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out you have to select one of the gradient nodes - on those you can define the color.